# Is there a faster way to detect an object by color using Emgu CV (openCV wrapper)?

Tags: c#, emgucv

The code below takes multiple seconds and I would like to detect an object by color faster so it can be displayed realtime.

```
grayImg = input.InRange(new Bgr(selectionRangeSlider1.SelectedMin,
                                selectionRangeSlider2.SelectedMin,
                                selectionRangeSlider3.SelectedMin),
                                new Bgr(selectionRangeSlider1.SelectedMax,
                                        selectionRangeSlider2.SelectedMax,
                                        selectionRangeSlider3.SelectedMax));
```

selectionRangeSlider is a custom Control that has 2 sliders on 1 valueline

```
Rectangle roi; //this rectangle is the product of rectangle recognition, now I want to check if the color of this recangle is at least 50% yellow

int whitePixels = 0;

for (int i = roi.X; (i < (roi.X + roi.Width)); i++)
{
    for (int j = roi.Y; (j < (roi.Y + roi.Height)); j++)
    {
        Byte currentVal = g.Data[i, j, 0];

        if (currentVal == 255) //255 means true: this pixel is yellow
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i + "," + j + " is yellow");
            whitePixels++;
        }
    }
}

if (whitePixels > ((roi.Width * roi.Height) / 2))
{
    // "more that half is yellow";
}
```

Comment: can you show me where you use the grayImg in the second code snippet? Because InRange shouln't be slow but doing a for i/j on each pixel is VERY slow! Please edit your answer to show the use of the grayImg

Comment: @Jean-François Côté theif (whitePixels > ((roi.Width * roi.Height) / 2)) is where I check if half of the Rectangle is a Dutch license plate by color, as we have a database with vehicle information for them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, if you want to find a color, I suggest that you split your image in HSV mode. It is more easy to track a color that way.

Then, instead of doing this double for/loop, juste use this simple function: [CountNonZero](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/1.5.0.0/Help/html/78abf622-70c1-9415-f7c5-27469fddf4a4.htm)

Don't ever write things to the console in a loop, unless for debuging because it's terribly slow.

So here is the final pipeline which should be realtime

1. Convert your image to HSV mode
2. Split in 3 channels
3. Do the InRange according to the color that your want to track (using your UI)
4. Do the ROI
5. CountNonZero.

Comment: This answer is good. But if you really want to use a double for loop, think of putting the X loop in the inner loop instead of Y, and put the Data property in a local variable outside of the for loops.

Comment: @rold2007 Could you please explain how this influences the performance as all pixels will be checked, whether the x or y is the inner var.

Comment: There is absolutely NO need for a loop, please read my answer carefully and use the CountNonZero function. This function does the "loop" in it's implementation but in a very efficient way.

Comment: @user2754599 Inverting your loops allow to take advantage of cache and prefetch. The CPU will thus read the next couple of byte after the pixel you are processing, speeding up the processing on the next pixel. As Jean-François Côté says you don't need this loop with his answer, I just told you in case you wanted to use such a loop for another algorithm.